# How Write to File and Append the content

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I have a `macro`inside a loop that is called often.
The problem is, when it's over and I check the .txt file, only the first entry is written inside the file.

#### Code:

```
.macro write_to_file(%string)
    li $v0, 13              # Syscall to Open File
    la $a0, fileOutput      # File Address (it doesnt exists yet)
    li $a1, 1               # Flag 1 = Write & Append
    li $a2, 0               # Mode 
    syscall                # Descriptor returned in $v0

    move $a0, $v0            # syscall 15 needs descriptor on $a0
    li   $v0, 15            # Write to File Syscall
    la   $a1, %string       # Output Buffer 
    li   $a2, 15            # Characters ammount to be write
    syscall
.end_macro
```

Comment: Check the return value (with a debugger).  Maybe MARS doesn't support opening the same file multiple times without closing it?

Comment: @PeterCordes So I could opoen it once in the beginning and close it only at the end of the program?

Comment: That's the normal way to deal with files, yes.  Most systems support having multiple files open at once (opposite of having the same file open multiple times), that's why there are descriptors.  IDK how closely MARS's syscall API matches Unix, but see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html

Comment: That worked. Thanks